# Definition of "linear graph" in this theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, definition, problem-solving

I'm reading Arthur Engel's "Problem Solving Strategies". On problem E8 he gives this theorem:

> Let $G$ be a linear graph of $n$ vertices. Then $G$ has a Hamiltonian path if the sum of the degrees of any two vertices is equal to or larger than $n-1$.

I'm confused on what he means. I googled "linear graph" and most of the results were about plotting 2-D functions. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) defines a linear graph as

> A path graph or linear graph is a graph whose vertices can be listed in the order $v_1, v_2, …, v_n$ such that the edges are $\{v_i, v_{i+1}\}$ where $i = 1, 2, …, n − 1$.

By that definition, wouldn't every linear graph have a Hamiltonian path? Am I understanding the theorem wrong or do I have a wrong definition?

The theorem seems to be related to Ore's Theorem, which I found from [this website](http://vle.du.ac.in/mod/book/print.php?id=5852&chapterid=4090):

> If $G$ is a simple graph with $n$ vertices, $n≥3$, such that $deg(u)+deg(v)≥n$ for every pair of non-adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ in $G$, then $G$ has an Hamilton’s circuit.

From Ore's, I've been thinking that "linear graph" just means a simple graph, but I'd like to make sure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a linear graph does seem to be just a simple graph. If you are looking for more information the following website included diagrams to clarify its theories: http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/TDK/FINAL/Chap%203.PDF
It also discusses the Hamilton path amongst other processes.

Comment: do you know if the theorem discussed is true for arbitrary simple graphs? I tried proving it using ore's theorem. Or even trying to follow the proof of Ore's theorem but I couldn't do it :(

Comment: No it does not generalize to arbitrary graphs

Comment: Outside links are generally frowned upon, but if you are willing to embed the relevant info, I think this would be a nice answer!

Comment: do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Just to be clear, I mean: Is the following statement true? "Let G be a simple graph of n vertices. Then G has a Hamiltonian path if the sum of the degrees of any two vertices is equal to or larger than n−1."